# How to mock current date time for passing a quality gate pass in java

Tags: java, java-time

I want to write testcase for current time logic. Here is my Java class.

```
public static void main(String []args){
        final ZonedDateTime passedDate = ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-03-09T05:00:00.000Z");
        if(isAgentConfirmationRequired()) {
         // Some codes...
          }
     }
private static boolean isAgentConfirmationRequired(final ZonedDateTime appointment)
    {
        final ZonedDateTime appointmentTime = appointment.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
        final ZonedDateTime todayTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
        final DayOfWeek dayOfToday = todayTime.toLocalDate().getDayOfWeek();
        if (dayOfToday == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY || dayOfToday == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
            // For weekend user can't update appointment for next business day.
            return appointmentTime.toLocalDate().isBefore(getNextAvailableBusinessDayForBooking(todayTime));
        }
        return todayTime.toLocalTime().isAfter(LocalTime.of(THREE_PM, 0)) && appointmentTime.toLocalDate().isBefore(getNextAvailableBusinessDayForBooking(todayTime));
    }

private LocalDate getNextAvailableBusinessDayForBooking(final ZonedDateTime today)
    {
        long nextAvailableDayCount = 2;
        final DayOfWeek day = today.toLocalDate().plusDays(nextAvailableDayCount).getDayOfWeek();
        if (day == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY || day == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
            nextAvailableDayCount += 2;
        } else if (day == DayOfWeek.MONDAY) {
            nextAvailableDayCount += 1;
        }
        return today.toLocalDate().plusDays(nextAvailableDayCount);
    }
```

If current time is not after 3pm then code coverage is less than 50%. Could someone suggest me how we can mock currentDateTime in testcase so when it comes to "ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"))" then it will used mocked dateTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tests should be independent when and where they are executed. To make them independent on the current enviroment time you should consider creating an interface that provides the current time.

e.g.

```
public interface TimeProvider {
    ZonedDateTime getCurrentZonedDateTime()
}
```

for production code you have a simple implementatation that returns the current time, and for tests you can mock its behaviour e.g. using [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/).

```
var timeProvider = Mockito.mock(TimeProvicer.class)
var testTime = ...
Mockito.when(timeprovider.getCurrentZonedDateTime()).thenReturn( testTime )
myProgram.setTimeProvider(timeProvider)
```

now the test will always return the same results.

Maybe you need to make sure that you do not call `ZonedDateTime.now()` (or any other method returning the current time) beside your default `TimeProvider` implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What should be inside TimeProvider implementation? Is it "return ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));"?

Comment: exactly. I thought that is so trivial that I dont need to mention that :)

Comment: No need to write a `TimeProvider`, just use `java.time.Clock`